# How to open for each url when I got the strings

Tags: php, mysql

I have got a problem with opening the urls. It will not open for each url when I have output the list of urls in the PHP after I have extract the urls from the mysql database.

Here is the php:

```
<?php

//Connect to the database
require_once('config.php');


$qrytable1="SELECT links FROM channels_list";
$result1=mysql_query($qrytable1) or die('Error:<br />' . $qry . '<br />' . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
  echo $row["links"];

  $baseUrl = file_get_contents($row["links"]);
  $domdoc = new DOMDocument();
  $domdoc->strictErrorChecking = false;
  $domdoc->recover=true;
  $domdoc->loadHTML($baseUrl);
  $links = $domdoc->getElementsByTagName('a');

  foreach ($links as $link)
  {
     echo "we are now opening for each url";

  }
}
```

Here is the output for the urls:

```
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=963
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=102
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=103
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=104
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=171
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=106
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=107
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=108
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=402
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=403
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=404
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=405
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=406
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=408
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=407
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=409
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=435
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=436
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=439
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=440
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=410
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=411
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=413
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=414
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=415
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=417
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=418
http://example.com.com/some_name/?id=421
```

I think there is a problem with this code:

```
$links = $domdoc->getElementsByTagName('a');
```

I don't have the html tag in my PHP page, it is only show the strings of the actual urls like what I show on above.

What I'm expect is I want to open each url when I get the list of urls from mysql.

Can you please help me with how I can open for each url when I get the urls from mysql database?

Comment: any idea??????????????????

Comment: what to you mean by "open for each url"? do you want as output a list of links, on which you can click? or do you want to download the contents of each url and save it somewhere?

Comment: @InnaTichman I want to output the list of links and open each link when I run domdoc

Comment: sorry, i can't completely understand, what do you mean by "open"? what should your program do? can you explain it in more details, so may be i can understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not exactly sure, what you mean by "open for each url".

if you want as output a list of links, on which you can click:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
    echo "<a href='".$row["links"]."'>".$row["links"]."</a>";
}
```

if you want to download the contents of each url:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
  $content_string = file_get_contents($row["links"]);
}
```

$content_string is a content of a page as string, not sure what you want to do with it.